# Content View AutoLayout

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

I am trying to add a container view to my project, and having trouble with auto layout. In this container view, I have subclassed it as a certain type of UIViewController, which I named ContainerViewController. I have tried looking to find this on stack overflow so apologies if it’s already been posted. Anyways, from this view controller, I am trying to achieve an effect similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpoNM.png), where a label is basically attached to the bottom of the ContainerViewController’s (the red view) view, and centered horizontally to this. However, whenever I try and do this (I am doing this programmatically), everything goes haywire. I am attaching my container view’s edges to the UILabels (all Zeroes), and the tops to the rectangles. I have tried setting the childviewcontroller in the -prepareforsegue method, I have tried changing the scaling factor, I have tried making the container view a fixed size, I have tried setting the authorize factor to flexible, I have tried nearly everything I can think of and I am not closer to the solution. When I set the background color of the view, it works exactly as it should: the background color turns to red like in the example above, in the amount of space that it should.

The problem: I added a UILabel to the ContainerViewController’s view in the -viewdidload method and found that the ContainerViewController’s view is the exact same size as size screen that I am using, and the UILabel attached to the bottom of that [view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Kib8.png), but I am only able to see the container screen’s views bounds. So the ContainerViewController’s view is not respecting the container view’s bounds. If I need to explain this any better or you have any questions let me know. Any help would be immensely appreciated, thanks!

TLDR: what is happening is that the container view has the right constraints for auto layout, and is only showing what happens in its bounds. However, the UIViewController inside the containerView has a view that is not respecting the bounds of the container view; its as if the uiviewcontroller has the same view size as the main view of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've basically solved it already: the view you've manually added to the container view does not automatically constrain itself to its parent as you might expect (I've mistakenly made this assumption myself). You need to explicitly bind the edges to the parent container view controller using programmatic auto layout.

I ended up using [PureLayout](https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout) to solve this myself. [See this answer to my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26228040/238948) for more details.

```
[newView autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I did not realize that it doesn’t follow that behavior, thanks for letting me know. I still have an issue however. For some reason my superview is nil, so that means that the ContainerViewController has not superview. However, I explicitly add the ContainerViewController’s view to the main view’s subview in the -prepareforsegue method. What am I doing wrong? Why does the ContainerViewController’s view have no superview?

Comment: I found out my issue, I realize now that I needed to add this method in the -ViewWillLayoutSubviews method, and unfortunately that didn’t work. Thanks for the suggestion though!