# Size classes not working when loading xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, size-classes

I have a custom view, that I load like this:

```
MyCustomView *my = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView" owner:self options:nil][0];
my.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[view addSubview:my];

//add constraints to make it fill superview
```

Problem is, on iPhone it only shows the size class Any|Any, ignoring all constraint changes I put in Compact|Regular.

Should I do anything else to make it read correctly the size classes on my xib file?

Comment: Checkout this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226608/auto-layout-xib-embedded-in-programmatic-uiview-not-sizing-to-parent

Comment: I already do that. Auto Layout is working fine, my problem is with Size Classes.

Comment: Try loading using UINib instead (just an idea, but it is more modern).